# Vector fields in projective coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-geometry

I am currently reading a course on microlocal analysis and I do not understand how they find some relations involving vector fields, after a change of coordinates.

Let $ (\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n) $ be the standard coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and we put :
$$ \rho = \frac{1}{\xi_1}, \, \, \, \nu_j = \frac{\xi_j}{\xi_1}$$
for $j = 2,\ldots, n$. Then, the following holds :

$$ \xi_1 \partial_{\xi_1} = - \rho \partial_{\rho} - \sum_{k = 2}^n \nu_k \partial_{\nu_k},$$

and there are three more but I do not see why that first relation is correct. Because it seems to me that $d\rho = d \left( \frac{1}{\xi_1}\right) = - \frac{1}{\xi^2_1} d \xi_1$, thus $\partial_{\rho} = - \xi^2_1 \partial_{\xi_1} $, and then $\rho \partial_{\rho} = -\xi_1 \partial_{\xi_1} $.
Any help would be nice, thanks !

Comment: I assume that $\partial_\rho$, for example, means the element of the dual basis to $(d\rho, d\nu_2, \dotsc, d\nu_n)$ that pairs to $1$ with $d\rho$.  Remember that dualization is a process applied to whole bases, not to individual basis vectors; so the equality $d\rho = -\frac1{\xi_1^2}d\xi_1$ can say something directly only about the dual basis to, say, $(d\rho, d\xi_2, \dotsc, d\xi_n)$ or $(d\xi_1, d\nu_2, \dotsc, d\nu_n)$, neither of which is what we want.

Comment: @LSpice I see, thank you. Is there a method to find these kind of relations between vector fields (after a change of coordinates) without using dual basis consisting in 1-forms ?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456554/vector-fields-in-projective-coordinates#comment1182429_456554), I'm not quite sure what you have in mind.  If I'm understanding you correctly, then $\partial_\rho$ is *defined* as an element of a dual basis, so I'm not sure how you could think of it without thinking of dual bases.  In your case, you could check that your proposed equality is true after dividing by $\xi_1$, just by pairing with $\xi_1, \dotsc, \xi_n$ and getting the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ and $(y^1, \dots, y^n)$, then \begin{align*} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}. \end{align*}

Therefore, if in your example, we set $x = \xi$ and $y = (\rho, \nu^2, \dots, \nu^n)$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^i} &= \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial\xi^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho} + \frac{\partial\nu^j}{\partial\xi^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu^j}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^1} &= -\frac{1}{(\xi^1)^2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho} + \xi^j\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu^j}\right)\\
&= -\frac{1}{\xi^1}\left(\rho\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho} + \nu^j\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu^j}\right).
\end{align*}
It follows that
$$ \xi^1\frac{\partial}{\partial\xi^1} = -\left(\rho\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho} + \nu^j\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu^j}\right). $$
I'll let you do the rest of the computation..

As for doing it via the dual basis, it is important to note that the formula for a given dual basis element depends on the *entire* basis. In particular, you cannot infer the formula for $\partial_\rho$ using only the formula for $d\rho$. So you have to compute the differential of all of the coordinates before doing anything else:
\begin{align*}
d\rho &= -\frac{d\xi^1}{(\xi^1)^2}\\
d\nu^j &= \frac{d\xi^j}{\xi^1} - \frac{\xi^j\,d\xi^1}{(\xi^1)^2}.
\end{align*}
If
$$
\partial_\rho = a^i\partial_{\xi^i},
$$
then
\begin{align*}
 1&= \langle d\rho,\partial_\rho\rangle\\
&= \left\langle -\frac{d\xi^1}{(\xi^1)^2},a^i\partial_{\xi^i}\right\rangle\\
&= -\frac{a^1}{(\xi^1)^2}\\
0 &= \langle d\eta^j,\partial_\rho\rangle\\
&= \left\langle \frac{d\xi^j}{\xi^1} - \frac{\xi^j\,d\xi^1}{(\xi^1)^2}, a^i\partial_{\xi^i}\right\rangle\\
&= \frac{a^j}{\xi^1} - \frac{\xi^ja^1}{(\xi^1)^2}.
\end{align*}
This leads to the same answer as above.

Comment: Everything is clear now, thank you very much